# Emojiareaone display all emoji on page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using emojiareaone from this link [Emojiareaone](https://jsfiddle.net/1v03Lqnu/12/),Its working fine on button click function,but on document ready i need to show the emoji with wrapper open and all the images inside the wrapper.Kindly suggest me

```
// I am using standalone
$("#standalone").emojioneArea({
standalone: true,
autocomplete: false
 });

</div>
<div class="span6">
 <div id="standalone" data-emoji-placeholder=":smiley">
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried something like on text change simulate button click, and do it if last text input is == to ':' or something like that?

Comment: i didn't get what you trying to explain, I want on document ready "emojionearea-wrapper" this has to be open and all the images should be displayed

Comment: Are you trying to display the emoji like if you click the smile button? if so you could simulate the click on the button... something like, if the user changes the input field, then check if the change includes the character that triggers the emoji to display, like `':'` if so, then trigger the event using `$("buttonID").click();`, but it can be annoing!

Comment: i want to display all the emoji images without button click and i am using standalone with single emoji selector

Comment: on page load I am using   $(".emojionearea").find(".emojionearea-standalone").addClass("focused");
    $(".emojionearea").find(".emojionearea-button").addClass("active");
    $(".emojionearea").find(".emojionearea-picker").removeClass("hidden"); it open the wrapper but images inside the wrapper  is not displayed first time,but when i click on button it close and again i open the images inside the wrapper will be displayed

Comment: You could try: `$(".emojionearea").find(".emojionearea-button").Click();` this trigger the click event in all of them, hopefully opening the `.emojionearea-picker` elements, with the content....

Comment: its not working, i tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try triggering the click event on the buttons, so it calls the code that loads the emojis instead of just showing the container.

```
$(".emojionearea-button").Click();
```